# Vertex Label with given name does not exist

Tags: graph, cassandra, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
public class Friendster {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */


public static void load(final TitanGraph graph,String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
    System.out.println("Inside Load Function");


    for (int i =0 ; sc.hasNext();i++)
    {
         TitanTransaction tx = graph.newTransaction();
        String friendLine = sc.nextLine();

        String friendList[]= friendLine.split(":");
        if(friendList.length==1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(friendList[1].equals("notfound"))
        {
            String human="human";
            tx.addVertex(T.label, human, "Name", "Not Found","No of Friends",0);

            // tx.commit();
        }
        else if(friendList[1].equals("private"))
        {
            String human="human";
            tx.addVertex(T.label, human, "Name", ""+friendList[0],"No of Freinds", "Private");
            System.out.println("Node Added : "+ friendList[0]);

            // tx.commit();
        }
        else
        {
            String human="human";
            int friends_count=friendList[1].split(",").length;

            tx.addVertex(T.label, human, "Name", ""+friendList[0],"No of Friends",friends_count);
            System.out.println("Node Added : "+ friendList[0]);
            String totalList[]=friendList[1].split(",");

            for(int j=0;j<totalList.length;j++)
            {
                 Iterator<Vertex> itr2=graph.traversal().V().has("Name", ""+totalList[j]);
                  if(!itr2.hasNext())
                  {
                      tx.addVertex(T.label, human, "Name", ""+totalList[j],"No of Friends",999);
                      System.out.println("Node Added : "+ totalList[j]);

                      //     tx.commit();
                  }
            }
        }
        tx.commit();

    }




       }

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("titan-cassandra.properties");


       //LOADING FROM FILE   
    load(g,"/media/laxmikant/New Volume/friends.txt");


      g.close();

}
```

}

This code gives error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex Label with given name does not exist: human
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.typemaker.DisableDefaultSchemaMaker.makeVertexLabel(DisableDefaultSchemaMaker.java:37)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.getOrCreateVertexLabel(StandardTitanTx.java:988)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.TitanBlueprintsTransaction.addVertex(TitanBlueprintsTransaction.java:101)
at Friendster.load(Friendster.java:79)
at Friendster.main(Friendster.java:133)
```

It was executing correctly before, suddenly it started throwing error.

If we run individual queries in gremlin shell it does not give error, but in java code it throws error, Why is that?

What is the issue with this code here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have set `schema.default=none` in your `titan-cassandra.properties` file, so automatic schema creation is disabled. When automatic schema creation is disabled, you need to define the schema (including all labels, properties, and indexes on vertices and edges) before you can use them.

Please refer to [Chapter 5: Schema and Data Modeling](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/schema.html#_automatic_schema_maker) in the Titan documentation for details on how to define a schema.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked.. Can you give me little help with this issue,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187601/how-to-load-millions-of-vertices-from-csv-into-titan-1-0-0-using-bulkloaderverte .

Answer (score 2):

When you put storage.batch-loading as true, then also automatic schema creation gets disabled, and you have to explicitly set the schema.

> ```
> lazy val graph = TitanFactory.build()
>   .set("storage.backend", storage_backend)
>   .set("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1")
>   .set("storage.cassandra.keyspace", "titan_graph_test")
>   .set("storage.batch-loading", "true") //this removes the consitency lock ,which don't work well with NSQL backends
>   .open()
> ```

```
 mgmt.makePropertyKey(TIME).dataType(classOf[String]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
 mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("interference").make()
```

Note that currently with TitanGraph , with these setting there seems to be a bug which prevents the Vertex to be created with label -- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/lFW1buC1Hms/tBV_hUUoAAAJ

But you can create a vertex without a label and add the above defined properties